# Sum and sort with Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, sum, ramda.js

I have an object which has object of array of numbers like so:

```
books = [{
  id: "a6113b1cd5d4617f63bb10abc874bea7",
  times: [{
    0: 1,
    1: 5
  }],
  length: 1,
  rating: 4.77,
}, {
  id: "b6113b1cd5d4617f63bb10abc874bea7",
  times: [{
    0: 8
  }],
  length: 1,
  rating: 2.6,
}]
```

I want to add **sort by times**, but that needs to be sum of all elements inside that object - In the example for the first object it is 1+5=6 and for the second object is 8 so the sorted end result is first object then second. This is what I have so far but it's incomplete. Do you have idea how do i get the sum of the array?

```
const timesSorting =  R.ascend(R.path(['times']))
const sorting = R.sortWith([timesSorting])
sorting(books)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use R.sortBy because you need to sort by a single property. Create a function that gets the `time` prop, use `R.chain` with `R.values` to get an array of all values in the time array, and sum them.

```js
const { pipe, prop, chain, values, sum, sortBy} = R

const getTimesSum = pipe(prop('times'), chain(values), sum);

const sorting = sortBy(getTimesSum)

const books = [{"id":"a6113b1cd5d4617f63bb10abc874bea7","times":[{"0":1,"1":5}],"length":1,"rating":4.77},{"id":"b6113b1cd5d4617f63bb10abc874bea7","times":[{"0":8}],"length":1,"rating":2.6}]

const result = sorting(books)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If `times` is always an array with a single object that has numerical indexes, you can simplify `times` to an array of numbers, and then it would be easier to sum:

```js
const { pipe, prop, sum, sortBy } = R

const getTimesSum = pipe(prop('times'), sum);

const sorting = sortBy(getTimesSum)

const books = [{
  "id": "a6113b1cd5d4617f63bb10abc874bea7",
  "times": [1, 5], // an array of numbers
  "length": 1,
  "rating": 4.77
}, {
  "id": "b6113b1cd5d4617f63bb10abc874bea7",
  "times": [8], // an array of numbers
  "length": 1,
  "rating": 2.6
}]

const result = sorting(books)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: If you change to `const getTimesSum = pipe(prop('times'), values, sum);`, then this will work for arrays or the original array-like objects.

Comment: It's an array like inside an array. I wasn't sure that there would be only one.

Comment: ooh, yes.  I'm clearly reading too fast today.  And that's a really nasty structure.  While `chain(values)` should do it, I agree that if possible it should be cleaned up.